# Creating a string of indexed numbers

Tags: java, indexof

I need to use the IndexOf(); method to store the different indexes in a word.  For example, say the word is "giraffe"  I want to make a code that stores indexes in a variable so it looks like the following:

```
input: System.out.println(indexes);
output: 4 5
```

the problem is that using a while loop executes the program and just displays the numbers.  I want to make indexes a string by using the following format:

```
String indexes = indexA + " " + indexB
```

where indexA would be the first location and indexB would be the next.  If there was more it would just keep creating new indexes (indexC, etc.) and keep adding them with a format that places a space in between them.

If there is an easier method to use to do this that would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm sorry, it isn't very clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  What are you indexing?  Are you looking for occurrences of the letter "f" in the word "giraffe"?  Why not just keep a List of integers and worry about formatting for display later?

Comment: The first location of what? Duplicate letters? Duplicate consecutive letters?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for the occurence of letters.  In giraffe, say I want to find the indexes of f.  I want it to save 4 and 5

Comment: And what are the indexes being stored for? Will they be used for rmore than just display?

Comment: So, I repeat, store the indexes as integers in an ArrayList<Integer> or an int[].  You can format for display later on.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have figured out how to gather the indices you want, and just need to format the output.

You can add all the indices to an array, then use Apache Commons's `StringUtils`:

```
Integer[] indices = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3};
String output = StringUtils.join(indices, " ");
System.out.println(output);
```

prints

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: A nice implementation of my idea.  Thanks @FiveNine